Read query parameters of a script tag source link inserted using JavaScript
My website has a library that loads external JavaScript sources like this.
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://example.com/file.js?test=123';
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);

How to programmatically detect whenever a script is added to the site using this method and further how to read the src parameter to access the query parameters (?test=123 in this case)?
I can do this for sendBeacon and XHR requests but what about scripts loaded as seen above?

Perhaps Mutation Observers... Have you had a look at this question in SO? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55249718/1533592
